# partial sum and negative sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know this is not a hard question but for some reasons I was not able to find an example to show the following statement is incorrect

Let $a_n>0$ and $a_1+a_2+.....+a_n<5$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent . This means the partial sum will be bounded but this not enough to say the series is convergent.  my second question is decreasing sequence with negative numbers has lower bound. I think I got this $$ -0.9,-.99,-.999,......$$ it has lower bound which is -1.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think that the statement is incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

It is enough because all the terms in the sequence $a_n$ are non-negative. This means that the sequence of partial sums is monotone increasing. A monotone and bounded sequence is convergent, this is well known.

Comment: Thank so much I misunderstand. you are right. How about the example ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your second question. An example to what are you trying to give? Of course your sequence has a lower bound.

Comment: @ Mark example for decreasing sequence with negative number has lower bound

Comment: Then yes, your example works.

Comment: Thank you a lot